# jquery toggleclass with different classes only the first function works

Tags: jquery, toggleclass

In an unordered list the li tag can either have a class of open (green) or closed (red).

```
<li class="open">
    <div class="field">U8</div>
    <input type="hidden" name="status" id="status" value=1>
    <div class="status">OPEN</div>
</li>
<li class="closed">
    <div class="field">U10</div>
    <input type="hidden" name="status" id="status" value=0>
    <div class="status">CLOSED</div>
</li>
```

At the bottom of the document before the closing body tag I have

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("li.open").click(function () {
        $(this).toggleClass("closed");
    });

    $("li.closed").click(function () {
        $(this).toggleClass("open");
    });
});
```

The first function li.open works fine!  The second li.closed does not do anything. =|  I'm just getting my feet wet with javascript and jquery.  So explain to me like I'm an idiot (which is partly true) what I did or am doing wrong!

In the end I wish to not only change the color but the value of the hidden input and change the OPEN to a CLOSED and vice versa.

I'm just boggled as why this doesn't work.  I even made classes open0, open1, closed0 and closed1 and used the 0's for the first function and 1's for the second.  Same results.

Appreciate the help/guidance/chiding =)

Comment: You can't have the same ID name on both input fields.

Comment: @Bojan Petkovski: well spotted (luckily unused) :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TrueBlueAussie is right, but a simpler solution may be to target the list items in a more general fashion, then update other elements based on the current class. I assume here that you have a class of `open` or `closed` on all list items initially.

```
$(document).on('click', 'ul#myList li', function () {
    $(this).toggleClass('open closed');

    if ($(this).hasClass('open')) {
        $(this).find('.myHiddenInputClass').val('OPEN');
        $(this).find('.myTextDivClass').text('OPEN');
    } else {
        $(this).find('.myHiddenInputClass').val('CLOSED');
        $(this).find('.myTextDivClass').text('CLOSED');
    }
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/skb3hujp/)

Notice that I target the inputs and text divs by DOM traversal and class, not by ID.

Comment: Credit to your shorter version also given, but I could not assume both at once as the result is very slightly different. `open AND closed` results in the original code.

Comment: I'm not seeing how both could exist at once on a given list item.

Comment: `.open` toggles `.closed` not `.open` and visa versa at the moment (weird I know) :)

Comment: This example has just taught me a lot!  I was experimenting most of the afternoon and was close but my attempts when I tried to just changing the text changed all the text of a class. Guess I'm going to have to learn this by trial and error they way I learned HTML 17 years ago by examples and asking and of course learning by my own mistakes! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to bind events to classes that do not exist at the time of binding. You are binding a single event handler to the first LI and a single event handler to the second LI.

The following uses delegated event handlers, attached to a non-changing ancestor element (in this case `document`).

It works by listening for the click event to bubble up to the ancestor, *then* applies the selector, *then* applies the function *to each matching element that caused the event*.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $(document).on("click", "li.open", function () {
        $(this).toggleClass("closed");
    });

    $(document).on("click", "li.closed", function () {
        $(this).toggleClass("open");
    });

});
```

The advantage is you can listen for events on elements (or classes) that do not exist yet.

Assuming you do not want any other code to execute it can be shortened to a single handler to toggle both classes (as isherwood describes).

Note: Your original code does something quite odd, in that it can wind up with both `open` and `closed` set on an item. That is probably not what you intended, but I could not make any assumptions :)

I would expect you actually wanted something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/L4t6h8sa/1/

```
$(function () {

    $(document).on("click", "li.open,li.closed", function () {
        $(this).toggleClass("closed open");
    });
});
```